# Angularjs select using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to filter cities using states with 2 select inputes 
when the first select change it value the second one should be changed according to the first select.

i have an array of items :

```
$scope.items = [
     {
         name:'state1',
         cities : [
              {id:1,name:'city1'},
              {id:2,name:'city2'},
         ]
     },
     {
         name:'state2',
         cities : [
              {id:1,name:'city1'},
              {id:2,name:'city2'},
         ]
     },
];
```

i tried this but its not working : 
first for states :

```
<select ng-model="state" ng-options="s.id as s.name in states"  ></select>
```

second for cities :

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-options="s.cities.id as s.cities.name for s in items | filter:{s.name:state}" ></select>
```

Answer (score 3):

The first dropdown selects the whole country object. The options of the second dropdown are the cities of the selected country :

```
<select class="country" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in items">
    <option value="">Choose country</option> 
</select>

<select ng-if="selectedCountry" class="city" ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city.name for city in selectedCountry.cities">
    <option value="">Choose city</option> 
</select>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/ydbgt87p/3/)**